# SQL calculation based on different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table and trying to subtract the total where a condition is True from the full total.

| Ticket | Amount | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 5.00 |  |
| 12 | 3.00 | X |
| 13 | 10.00 |  |
| 14 | 2.00 | X |

My query was

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM Table
MINUS 
SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM Table
WHERE Code = 'X'
```

So the answer should be 20 - 5= 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two possible queries:

```
-- Use IF operator 
SELECT SUM(amount) - SUM(IF(code = 'X', amount, 0)) FROM tbl;

-- Use implicit MySQL conversion boolean to int (true => 1)
SELECT SUM(amount) - SUM(amount * (code = 'X')) FROM tbl;
```

[SQL editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/2612a02e232c8af95aeac4e23e07e1a5/)